# Modify Image Source With The_Content Filter?

Tags: posts, images, filters, the-content, regex

I'm very inexperienced with regex, however I'm trying to create a function that filters through `the_content()`  and `get_the_content()` in order to modify the SRC of all images. The intended purpose would be to modify the URL's to use `http://i0.wp.com/` instead of `http://`. This would allow posts to utilize the Photon API without needing the JS side of Photon..

I know I need to hook into `the_content()` using a filter in order to accomplish this, but I was unable to accoplish this using `str_replace()`, so I'm assuming using `preg_replace()` would work.

Also, if it's possible to add `?quality=70&strip=all` to the end of the URL this would help decrease page speed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: That wouldn't work, because I'm referring to images that are already in the_content, I'm not running that function myself...

Comment: Try regexbuddy to write your regex. Yes you need regex for this.

Comment: I would say "use the Javascript". `regex` on markup is very tricky and very error prone.

Comment: I'm not looking to use JavaScript, I'm looking to use PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give it a try:

```
$str = '<img src="http://myserver.mydomain/picture.png" />';
$pattern ='#<img src="http://.*/(.*)" />#';
$replace = '<img src="http://http://i0.wp.com/$1?quality=70&strip=all />"';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $str);
```

The $pattern is quite simple and very specific. You might need to generalize it a bit more but it should show you the direction to go. E.g. it takes no care of possible whitespace. A first attempt to take care of this:

```
$pattern ='#<\s*img\s*src\s*=\s*"http://myserver.mydomain/(.*)"\s*/\s*>#';
```

Comment: This looks great, I actually need to remove the URL protocol from the original source when creating the new source link. So I'll take a look at this and work it from there, thanks!